# How to generate global, named javascript functions in coffeescript, for Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, google-apps-script

I'd like to write Javascript scripts for [Google Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/) using CoffeeScript, and I'm having trouble generating functions in the expected form.

Google Apps Script expects a script to contain top-level, named functions. (I may be using the wrong terminology, so I'll illustrate what I mean with examples...)

For example, this function is happily recognised by Google Apps Script:

```
function triggerableFunction() {
   // ...
}
```

... while this function is not (it will parse, but won't you won't be able to trigger it):

```
var nonTriggerableFunction;

nonTriggerableFunction = function() {
  // ...
};
```

I've found that with CoffeeScript, the closest I'm able to get is the `nonTriggerableFunction` form above. What's the best approach to generating a named function like `triggerableFunction` above?

I'm already using the 'bare' option (the `-b` switch), to compile
   without the top-level function safety wrapper.

The one project I've found on the web which combines CoffeeScript and Google App Script is [Gmail GTD Bot](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/gmail-gtd-bot), which appears to do this using a combination of back-ticks, and by asking the user to manually remove some lines from the resulting code. (See the end of the [script](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/gmail-gtd-bot/blob/master/src/GtdBot.coffee), and the 'Installation' section of the [README](https://github.com/TobiaszCudnik/gmail-gtd-bot#readme)). I'm hoping for a simpler and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 15):

CoffeeScript does not allow you to create anything in the global namespace implicitly; but, you can do this by directly specifying the global namespace.

```
window.someFunc = (someParam) -> 
    alert(someParam)
```

Comment: This creates a anonymous function, not a named one. The anonymous function is then assigned to someFunc. Its obvious if you put a breakpoint in your new function and look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this can be done using a single line of [embedded Javascript](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded) for each function.

E.g. this CoffeeScript:

```
myNonTriggerableFunction = ->
  Logger.log("Hello World!")

`function myTriggerableFunction() { myNonTriggerableFunction(); }`
```

... will produce this JavaScript, when invoking the coffee compiler with the 'bare' option (the -b switch):

```
var myNonTriggerableFunction;

myNonTriggerableFunction = function() {
  return Logger.log("Hello World!");
};

function myTriggerableFunction() { myNonTriggerableFunction(); };
```

With the example above, Google Apps Script is able to trigger `myTriggerableFunction` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a global named function (yes, it's a little hacky, but far less that using backticks):

```
# wrap in a self invoking function to capture global context
do ->
  # use a class to create named function
  class @triggerableFunction
    # the constructor is invoked at instantiation, this should be the function body
    constructor: (arg1, arg2) ->
      # whatever
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to generate a global named function. This is what it produces, when using the -b switch:

    (function() {
      return this.triggerableFunction = (function() {

        function triggerableFunction(arg1, arg2) {}

        return triggerableFunction;

      })();
    })();

Comment: Did you run the code in a browser ? The function is global because it is attached to the global context. And it is named : `triggerableFunction.name === "triggerableFunction"`. Of course, it does not generate a function statement, but I believe that is not what was asked.

Comment: The code ran within the Google Apps Script engine rather than a browser. I was indeed asking how to generate a function statement, which the Google Apps Script engine seems to require. The workaround used by 'gmail-gtd-bot' (using back-ticks) worked for me.

Comment: I need to attach a function to global namespace so I can call it after a pjax partial page load. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

juste use @ in script, exemple of my code :

```
@isArray = (o)->
  Array.isArray(o)
```

it will be compiled in :

```
(function() {

  this.isArray = function(o) {
    return Array.isArray(o);
  };

}).call(this);
```

this = window in this case, so it's global function