# Google Apps Script CoffeeScript

Tags: google-apps-script

What are some ways of hacking CoffeeScript into the Google Apps Script Editor (not an external editor)?  I realize I won't get autocomplete, but I would like to use CoffeeScript inside the google editor nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because it's a JavaScript execution environment, not a CoffeeScript execution environment.  Google would have to add support for this themselves.

You could write locally in CoffeeScript and put the output code into the Google Apps Script editor?

Comment: That approach is described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059475/how-to-generate-global-named-javascript-functions-in-coffeescript-for-google-a) and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't looked at it, this seems like it might be helpful:
[A CoffeeScript template for Google Apps Script development](https://github.com/joscha/google-apps-script-coffee-template)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, it is better if you could include the most relevant information into your answer.