# Coffeescript - InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am pretty new with coffee Script and i want to use it to load a google map. 
However, it consistently keeps producing the error;

```
InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
```

The coffeescript code looks like this;

```
$.ajax '/locations',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'json'
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            alert "error"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            initMap = ->
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                center:
                  lat: 0.324680
                  lng: 32.572633
                zoom: 10
              )

loadScript = ->
  script = document.createElement("script")
  script.type = "text/javascript"
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDiX1sI3oEJBncfz3eFh4AV5zX9f9LGibo&callback=initMap"
  document.body.appendChild script
  return

#
# $(window).load ->

loadScript()
```

From the Suggestions below, tried this;

```
$.ajax '/locations',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'json'
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            alert "error"
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            @buses = data

initMap = ->
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    center:
      lat: 0.324680
      lng: 32.572633
    zoom: 10
  )

loadScript = ->
  script = document.createElement("script")
  script.type = "text/javascript"
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDiX1sI3oEJBncfz3eFh4AV5zX9f9LGibo&callback=initMap"
  document.body.appendChild script
  return

loadScript()

 # $(window).load ->
```

Comment: Are you trying to call initMap before the ajax request comes back? your not defining the function until then...

Comment: @jared nope! the call is after loading the js. Check edit

Comment: initMap is in an invisible scope here.

Comment: AJAX is *asynchronous*. I also don't know how this is supposed to work, since your initMap function expects google maps to be already be there, and your google maps callback expects initMap to already be there. You will have to define one of them not in terms of the other.

Comment: @Brian it also, depending on the resolution of the ajax request vs the maps api request, not have even been defined yet.

Comment: It has to be `window.initMap = ->` if you rely on async load & callback. This is duplicate of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13939086/673826